# "Continue" button not showing while installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, command-line

I've reached the installation screen on my netbook and have ticked all the screens (download updates etc).  The requisite memory is ticked and the internet access is ticked but I can't find a "Install" or "go" button to continue. How do I access the lower part of the small screen?

Answer (score 3):

use the TAB key to get to the next button, then press enter

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the screen resolution to a smaller value.  The window is quite big, and your netbook may not have the screen size to display the "Continue" button (which is at the bottom of the window).

First, go to system settings by clicking the icon on the launcher with a gear.

[image]

Click on "Displays", then click on the "Resolution" option.

[image]

Choose a value on the options (more options should show up on your netbook).  Try a smaller value like 1024x768 until the "Continue" button shows up.

After you click "Continue", change the option back to the original one.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happened to me. If you try Emerson Hsieh's solution, you'll notice that the 'apply' button is off of your screen. Try the following:

1. Close the installation window.
2. Hit `CTRL+ALT+T` to open a terminal window.
3. Type `xrandr` into the terminal window and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. All of the displays connected to your computer will be displayed. Find the one that you are using.
5. Find your screen's native resolution.
6. Type `--output YourScreenName --mode YourResolution` and hit return. For example, `--output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080`.
7. Close the terminal window and run the setup from the desktop. You should be good to go!